# Insert or Update value of one column against specific column in room DB android

Tags: android, database, insert

I need to insert or update a value of one column against specific column using **Room DB** like if column 'id' is 2 then put value inside column 'answer' . I need to use WHERE clause but do not know the exact syntax and way.

`@Insert
    @Query(INSERT INTO "+ TABLE +" WHERE id = :id")
    long insertSkillValue(String id,String value);`

I need to know the missing part of query

Comment: what are you getting in error? dont use @Query if you are using @Insert!

Comment: Yes that was an error.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Query("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET column_name1=:value WHERE id=:id")
long insertSkillValue(String id, String value);
```

Something like this?

Comment: I actually do not want to replace or update all the columns. Just need to update two columns. But i get it. I need to use SET inside query.

Comment: Yes. I was looking for this. Thank you

Comment: but this just replaces the existing value. I want to add a new value to the existing one